# Is it possible to have one fragment class common to different fragments, all having the same structure?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I am new to Android development, and I was wondering whether it is possible to have one fragment class common to different fragments all having the same structure (a `ListView` and a `TextView`).

I will illustrate what I mean: The program has a fragment which displays a text view and a list view. This list view displays the names of subjects such as Maths, physics, computing and so on. When the item is clicked, I want to replace (this) fragment with another fragment using the same layout structure as the previous fragment, the only difference being the text view displayed, the name of the item clicked and the list displaying the module of that subject. E.g clicking on maths will display:

```
TextView: Mathematics, ListView: Core 1, Core 2, Core 3, Core 4 and so on.
```

And the same thing must be repeated for every subject using the same layout for their fragment.

So my question is: instead of creating different fragment class for the each subject, is there a way that I can create one fragment class only that will be common to all subject fragments, and modify it at runtime? (Changing the `textView` name and changing the the `String` array user in `ArrayAdapter`)?

Thank you!

My activity_main layout looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/display_content_editText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:editable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment layout that I want to use look like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subject_textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/subject_list_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment class look like this

```
package com.example.fragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SubjectFragment extends Fragment {

    OnItemSelected onItemSelected;

    ListView listView;
    String[] subjectName;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    TextView textView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.model_list_fragment, container, false);

        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subject_textView);
        textView.setText(R.string.subject_textView);

        //Setting up the list view and its adapter
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.subject_list_id);
        subjectName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.subject_list_array);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.custom_list_view, R.id.custom_view_id, subjectName);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        //Set the click listener for the list view created
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int  position, long id) {
                String subjectName =  parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                onItemSelected.itemSelected(subjectName);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            onItemSelected = (OnItemSelected) activity;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemSelected{
        void itemSelected(String subjectName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply implement a click listener for the control element - the list item in your case.In the onclick of that item simply change the respective text view content